# How to stop uninstalling android app using or ask password for enterprise app

Tags: android

I am developing Enterprise application and I want to know when the employees uninstalling the application.I have tried with DevicePolicyManager .I have googled it all are suggesting DevicePolicyManager,I have tried with http://www.truiton.com/2014/01/android-devicepolicymanager-example/ but it is setting password for lock screen and but while i uninstall it is moving security->deviceAdministrators, and when i uncheck my application i can able to uninstall it.I want to ask password while uninstalling.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is device policy management.  You need to be the device owner, not just a device administrator.  At that point, you can control the ability to install or uninstall applications.  But there's no ability to just password protect a single app from being uninstalled-  you have to control the phone entirely and prevent uninstalls in general.

Don't do this without really studying what this does and how to do things correctly.  After becoming device owner, the device is basically under your control.  This should not be done on any hardware you don't own, and it should not be done for a single app, but as part of a policy for managing all apps on the device.

There is also a way around this-  factory reset will make it forget device ownership.  You can prevent factory reset, but if the user is smart enough to unlock his boot loader he can reset it from there.

Comment: Thanks,Can help me little more about this issue.

Comment: Thanks ,if resets it is not our problem. I want to know the employee has unistalled the application  and how can we be owner of the device can you please tell me any example please

Comment: WHen you're device owner, (set via the dpm command from an adb shell), you can set various policies for the device.  One of them is             UserManager.DISALLOW_UNINSTALL_APPS.  This disallows any app on the phone from being uninstalled by the user (I think, but have never tested, that your app can still uninstall one).

Comment: @Sanjeev  There's no ability to do that.  You can detect an app has been uninstalled from a 2nd app.  You can prevent any app from being uninstalled with device ownership.  But there's no way to have code run before an app in uninstalled.

Comment: my last question can you please give any example for being device ownership or You can detect an app has been uninstalled from a 2nd app